# How do you get the shipping address back from an Adaptive Payment API call?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

How are you supposed to get the shipping info back from a **Parallel Payment**, using *PayPal's Adaptive API* system? Normally it would just get passed back as **payer_country**, etc - when the IPN script is requested. However, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Here are the params being passed in when the IPN script is called:

```
transaction[0].amount 
transaction[0].id 
verify_sign 
transaction[1].receiver 
reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error 
transaction[1].pending_reason 
transaction[0].pending_reason 
transaction[1].id_for_sender_txn 
transaction[0].invoiceId 
payment_request_date 
test_ipn 
cancel_url 
charset 
return_url 
transaction[0].status_for_sender_txn 
ipn_notification_url 
transaction[1].is_primary_receiver 
transaction[1].status 
transaction_type 
transaction[1].amount 
transaction[0].status 
log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction 
transaction[0].receiver 
status 
transaction[0].id_for_sender_txn 
action_type 
fees_payer 
pay_key 
transaction[1].status_for_sender_txn 
transaction[0].paymentType 
transaction[1].invoiceId 
transaction[1].id 
sender_email 
notify_version 
transaction[1].paymentType 
transaction[0].is_primary_receiver
```

If I then do a `PaymentDetails` API call, I get back stuff like:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'currencyCode' => 'USD',
  'responseEnvelope' => {
                          'correlationId' => '9944330ab9a8c',
                          'timestamp' => '2014-04-07T06:08:16.094-07:00',
                          'ack' => 'Success',
                          'build' => '10273932'
                        },
  'status' => 'COMPLETED',
  'senderEmail' => 'andy.aaaa@ultranerds.co.uk',
  'cancelUrl' => 'http://somesite.net/paypal/cancel.html',
  'paymentInfoList' => {
                         'paymentInfo' => [
                                            {
                                              'pendingRefund' => 'false',
                                              'receiver' => {
                                                              'accountId' => 'NY3AD33DD739C',
                                                              'email' => 'andy-xxx@ultranerds.com',
                                                              'amount' => '65.00',
                                                              'invoiceId' => '1022',
                                                              'primary' => 'false',
                                                              'paymentType' => 'GOODS'
                                                            },
                                              'transactionId' => '8E1114341X895213Y',
                                              'senderTransactionStatus' => 'COMPLETED',
                                              'senderTransactionId' => '5EV71352C33256006',
                                              'transactionStatus' => 'COMPLETED',
                                              'refundedAmount' => '0.00'
                                            },
                                            {
                                              'pendingRefund' => 'false',
                                              'receiver' => {
                                                              'accountId' => 'YYP5C69YWCMKE',
                                                              'email' => 'andy.yyy@gmail.com',
                                                              'amount' => '15.00',
                                                              'invoiceId' => '1023',
                                                              'primary' => 'false',
                                                              'paymentType' => 'GOODS'
                                                            },
                                              'transactionId' => '68H86656UP574062X',
                                              'senderTransactionStatus' => 'COMPLETED',
                                              'senderTransactionId' => '2XW88939LK1112523',
                                              'transactionStatus' => 'COMPLETED',
                                              'refundedAmount' => '0.00'
                                            }
                                          ]
                       },
  'feesPayer' => 'EACHRECEIVER',
  'actionType' => 'CREATE',
  'ipnNotificationUrl' => 'http://somesite.net/paypal/test_ipn.cgi',
  'sender' => {
                'useCredentials' => 'false',
                'accountId' => 'B74RBM5F6SLZG',
                'email' => 'andy.aaa@ultranerds.co.uk'
              },
  'returnUrl' => 'http://somesite.net/paypal/success.html',
  'payKey' => 'AP-4EK17906VB6613533',
  'reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError' => 'false'
};
```

As you can see, there is no reference to the delivery address at all. How are you supposed to get that info back?

**UPDATE:** Mmm ok, so it looks like **GetShippingAddresses** is what I need - but for some reason its coming back with nothing in when I call it:

`{"requestEnvelope":{"errorLanguage":"en_US","detailLevel":"ReturnAll"},"key":"AP-1B1377463N9785350"} /GetShippingAddresses_API_Operation/`

...simply returns:

```
{
    'responseEnvelope' => {
                      'correlationId' => '3a4443aed09c9',
                      'timestamp' => '2014-04-07T06:40:35.460-07:00',
                      'ack' => 'Success',
                      'build' => '10273932'
                    }
}
```

I'm a bit baffled as to why its doing that. Any suggestions?

I found a quote here:

http://go.developer.ebay.com/devzone/articles/using-paypals-adaptive-payments-and-google-app-engine-build-online-market-python-part-3

> Unfortunately, although this follows the process recommended by
>   PayPal's documentation, it doesn't work. There's currently a bug in
>   PayPal's Adaptive Payments implementation. For a traditional payment,
>   the shipping address is not collected; for embedded payments, the
>   GetShippingAddresses call does not return the shipping address.
>
> PayPal has acknowledged the bug and indicated that it expects to have
>   this fixed in April 2011. If you need shipping addresses right now,
>   the recommendation is to collect them on your site rather than relying
>   on the PayPal API.

That was from 2011... but is this still the case??

Sorry to bump - but has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, well I got my answer - but unfortunately its not what I was hoping for:

> Yes, unfortunately this feature is only available for embedded payment
>   flow.
>   https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-embeddedPayment-curl-etc/
>
> If you're using embedded payment flow, then you can retrieve the
>   address on their PayPal account by passing in
>   senderOptions.requireShippingAddressSelection = true during
>   SetPaymentOption API call. You can then retrieve it via
>   GetShippingAddresses API call.

So it looks like really what I need to do, is ask the user to provide their shipping information BEFORE sending them to paypal, then storing it. Not ideal - but I guess you just have to work with what you got!

Comment: this is me with the paypal api right now:   (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻